# Testing Angular code wrapped in $scope.$apply() in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test the following code, which only runs if `$scope.checkOutDate` is **undefined** in the first place.

```
$scope.checkInUpdatesCheckOutDate = function(checkOutViewValue){
  var checkInDateInMilliseconds = new Date($scope.checkInDate).getTime(),
    InMilliseconds = new Date(checkOutViewValue).getTime(),
    diffBetweenCheckOutAndCheckIn = Math.floor((checkOutDateInMilliseconds - checkInDateInMilliseconds) / oneDay);

  if(diffBetweenCheckOutAndCheckIn > 0){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.checkOutDate = $filter('date')(new Date(checkOutViewValue).getTime(), 'EEEE, M/dd/yyyy');
      $scope.nights = diffBetweenCheckOutAndCheckIn;
    });
  }
}
```

But when I run my jasmine test, and test the $scope.checkOutDate is never changed from undefined. My function is supposed to set `$scope.checkOutDate` equal to the `checkOutViewValue` (the current value in the input on the view).

Here is my test:

```
describe('checkInUpdatesCheckOutDate', function(){

      it('should work', function(){
        $scope.checkInDate = '9/17/15';
        var checkOutViewValue = '9/20/15';
        var result = $filter('date')(new Date(checkOutViewValue).getTime(), 'EEEE, M/dd/yyyy');
        $scope.checkInUpdatesCheckOutDate ();

        expect($scope.checkOutDate).toEqual(result);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `$scope.$apply()` right after your function call. That should trigger a 'digest' cycle and will execute the code in the 'apply' block.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the code inside a `$scope.$apply` function, just call `$scope.$digest()` in it's place